# GSUTIL CP files delayed

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I use GSUTIL command line tool in Google cloud to copy files from one GCS folder to another GCS folder and then do some data processing. Lately I found some data loss in the final target (BQ table), when dig deeper I found out the issue is around the file copy, when I copy large number of files, 3K~5K e,g, seems some files are not copied to the target folder in time and the data processing starts, those files eventually being copied over but too late for the data processing, what can I do to prevent this happen? any flag/configuration in GSUTIL command line tool to make sure the copy fully complete? the command I've been using:
gsutil -m cp gs://folder1/* gs://folder2/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the gsutil command completed successfully (exit status 0) the files should all be copied, but they may not show up immediately in the bucket listing (GCS bucket listings are eventually consistent). If your data processing job is operating by listing the bucket to find the files to process that would explain the situation you're seeing. To avoid this problem you could generate a manifest of the object names you copied and feed it to your data processing job, rather than depending on bucket listings.

(The bucket listing will eventually show all the files, but you can't depend on it having the complete listing immediately after uploading the files.)